# Get iframe url firefox

Tags: internet-explorer, google-chrome, firefox, iframe

What could be the reason why I am able to access the url of my iframe in chrome but not in firefox or any other browser?
When not using chrome I always get "Error: Permission denied to access proberty 'href'".

Both, the main page and the iframe page, use the same protocol, the same port, the same host and even are in the same directory.

Here is the line causing the problem:

```
var url=$("#site")[0].contentWindow.location.href;
```

Comment: Is the HTML of the outer page short enough to share?

Comment: about 100 lines of html + 40 script lines